# ReactJs: How to handle empty array with map function inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I m trying to print table with some JSON data, but I am not able to render empty array when I am using map method.

JSON DATA :

```js
    [{
 "id": 6,
 "firstname": "Sharon",
 "lastname": "Jenkins",
 "specialties": []
}, {
 "id": 2,
 "firstname": "Helen",
 "lastname": "Leary",
 "specialties": [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "radiology"
 }]
}, {
 "id": 4,
 "firstname": "Rafael",
 "lastname": "Ortega",
 "specialties": [{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "surgery"
 }]
}, {
 "id": 5,
 "firstname": "Henry",
 "lastname": "Stevens",
 "specialties": [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "radiology"
 }]
}]
```

My Code :

```js
 {this.state.vets.map(vet =><tr><td>{vet.firstname}</td>
                  {  
                                  
                  vet.specialties.map((subitem,i) => {
                       
                    return <td>{subitem.name}</td> })}<td>EDIT</td><td id={vet.firstname}><div class="funkyradio">
```

Now I am getting the following error
[image]

As Sharon doesn't have a specialist, I need to print as N/A.

How can I check the specialities are empty and print N/A.

Comment: This is happening because the specialities array of your first object is empty so the second map function does not iterate over that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try rendering always the TD tag, like:

```
{
  this.state.vets.map(vet =>
    <tr>
      <td>{vet.firstname}</td>
        <td>                
          {vet.specialties.map((subitem,i) => {
            return <span>{subitem.name}</span>
          })}
        </td>
        <td>EDIT</td>
        <td id={vet.firstname}>
          <div class="funkyradio">
```

Answer (score 2):

use conditional statment like this

```
{ this.state.vets.length > 0 
 ? this.state.vets.map(()=>Your logic)
 : <Your custom message/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<table>
        {dataJSON.map(({ id, firstname, lastname, specialties }) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td> {`${firstname} ${lastname}`} </td>
              <td> {specialties.map(specialty => specialty.name).join(",")} </td>
              <td> <span> EDIT </span> </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly for readability, instead of using the object property, I would create a separate function that will return the specialties, if any, otherwise N/A